# SelectItem is not selecting item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

View (RelacionamentoConvidado.cshtml)

```
@Html.DropDownList("Foi_Emitido", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Foi_Emitido, @SRSVP.Util.Constante.HTML_HELPER_DROPDOWN_EMPTY_VALUE, new { @class = "input-small" })
```

Controller (EventoConvidadoController)

```
ViewBag.Foi_Emitido = new SelectList(Common.SimNao(model.foi_emitido), "Value", "Text");
```

Common.cs (Static Class)

```
public static List<SelectListItem> SimNao(object selectedItem)
{
    List<SelectListItem> _returnList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    SelectListItem _mList = new SelectListItem();

    _mList = new SelectListItem() { Text = "Sim", Value = "true", Selected = selectedItem == null ? false : selectedItem.ToString().Equals("true") };
    _returnList.Add(_mList);

    _mList = new SelectListItem() { Text = "Não", Value = "false", Selected = selectedItem == null ? false : selectedItem.ToString().Equals("false") };
    _returnList.Add(_mList);

    return _returnList;
}
```

When the page is loaded select item is not select item that return from my database.

How can I do this?

Comment: If `selectedItem` is `bool`, then it returns `"True"` or `"False"` string values. Try to check for those ones, or better use `string.Compare(selectedItem, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead

Comment: Also take a look at this link which will explain when to use `.Equals()` vs `==` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx

Comment: Is `model.foi_emitido` a `bool` property?

Answer (score 0):

This Often happens when the Select List and bound variable share the same name --**Foi_Emitido**. Try renaming the ViewBag SelectList

```
@Html.DropDownList("Foi_Emitido", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Foi_Emitido_SelectList, @SRSVP.Util.Constante.HTML_HELPER_DROPDOWN_EMPTY_VALUE, new { @class = "input-small" })
```

Controller (EventoConvidadoController)

```
ViewBag.Foi_Emitido_SelectList= new SelectList(Common.SimNao(model.foi_emitido), "Value", "Text");
```